# Is there an equivalent to PreApplicationStartMethod for WPF Applications?

Tags: wpf, dependency-injection

For those that don't know, you can mark an assembly with the [PreApplicationStartMethod](http://haacked.com/archive/2010/05/16/three-hidden-extensibility-gems-in-asp-net-4.aspx), which will define a method that gets called before Application_Start in an ASP.NET site (if you're using .NET 4). I love using this in an Onion Architecture for defining a method that does all the setup for Dependency Injection.

My question is... is there any equivalent way of doing the same thing for a thick client application, such as one written in WPF?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If we knew that then a solution might be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

For a WPF application it doesn't make much sense to mark an assembly with an attribute, since you are in control of which code will execute anyway.

A good place to do this initialization would be the [`OnStartup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.onstartup.aspx) method.

Comment: You can say the exact same thing about an ASP.NET application that you've written... and yet the attribute still exists for ASP.NET

Answer (score 0):

In your App.xaml remove the StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml"

Then in your App.xaml.cs I do this:

```
   public partial class App : Application
   {
      private IWindsorContainer _container;
      private IView _view;

      protected override void OnStartup(StartupEventArgs e)
      {
         base.OnStartup(e);

         _container = new WindsorContainer();

         /// Register your interfaces with your concrete implementations.

         // we'll do View first in this example (some do view first others do ViewModel first)
         _view = _container.Resolve<IView>();
         _view.Show();
      }
   }
```